# Can I Control Specific VC++ Compiler Optimizations?

Tags: c++, assembly, visual-c++, x86

I am working on a project that references another binaries functions. In order to obtain said functions, I need to find them programmatically via pattern matching/scanning. As a way to make this easier I have compiled parts of the code in a separate project and are comparing things between the two projects in a disassembler to pull the needed byte information out to scan for the functions.

However, I have hit a point where VC++'s optimizations are getting in the way of some things and I am wondering if there is a way to disable specific optimizations per-instruction or similar.

As an example, this is part of a function from the target binary:

```cpp
push    ebp
mov     ebp, esp
push    ecx
push    [ebp+arg_4]
push    [ebp+arg_0]
call    sub_00000000
add     esp, 8
cmp     dword ptr [eax+4], 3
```

And the same part of the function from my personal compile of the code:

```cpp
push    ebp
mov     ebp, esp
push    ecx
push    [ebp+arg_4]
push    [ebp+arg_0]
call    sub_00000000
pop     ecx
pop     ecx
cmp     dword ptr [eax+4], 3
```

In order to get the code to get this close I had to use specific project settings and tinkering with them any other way yields much different output. My issue here is that the stack alignments are being converted from 'add' instructions to 'pop' due to the minimial code optimization being enabled. I can't change this though or else I get entirely different output.

Is there any way to specifically disable the 'add esp, ??' from being converted to the proper amount of pops?

Comment: Visual C++ has undocumented options for controlling optimization, but I doubt there's any that controls the very specific optimization you're asking about. You might want to see if you can get a hold of the version of the compiler that produce the binaries your scanning.

Comment: this kind of optimization - can not, and for what ?

Comment: @Ross What "undocumented options" are you thinking of? The ones [pseudo-documented here](http://www.geoffchappell.com/studies/msvc/cl/cl/options/)? Or do you know of others? (I realize this isn't relevant to epzap's question, but the claim intrigues me.)

Comment: @CodyGray I've only seen them mentioned occasionally, like in one post here that reported that Microsoft support had told them about some undocumented option to work around a code generation bug. That list you linked is for the version of the compiler included with Visual C++ .NET 2002, so it's unfortunately long out of date.

Answer (score 3):

> I am working on a project that references another binaries functions. In order to obtain said functions, I need to find them programmatically via pattern matching/scanning.

Why? If the binary is stable enough that you can rely on pattern matching/scanning, then the binary is stable enough that you can just hard-code the addresses. Either of these are subject to change when the binary is recompiled, so they are both equally fragile. Just analyze the binary ahead of time, figure out the addresses of the functions you want, and call them directly. It'll also be faster.

> I am wondering if there is a way to disable specific optimizations per-instruction or similar.

No, there isn't. [The optimization settings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k1ack8f1.aspx) are very loosely-grained. You get to specify whether you want to optimize for space or time, you get to specify a minimum available instruction set, and (on 32-bit builds) you get to specify whether frame pointers are elided. That's basically it. There are some other optimization settings (and, apparently, [according to Ross Ridge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44731590/can-i-control-specific-vc-compiler-optimizations#comment76446338_44731590), some undocumented options, with which I am largely unfamiliar), but none that are relevant here.

Judging by the sample disassembly provided, it appears that what you want to control is whether the stack is cleaned after a `__cdecl` function call by a series of `pop`s or by simply `add`ing the appropriate number of bytes to the stack pointer.

From my tests, when there are only one or two parameters, MSVC will prefer `pop` to clean the stack when optimizing for size (`/O1`). When there are more than two parameters, or when optimizing for speed (`/O2`) regardless of the number of parameters, it will prefer `add esp, x`. This holds true on *all* versions of Visual Studio (I tested VS 6, VS 2005, VS 2008, VS 2010, VS 2013, and VS 2015 explicitly). This actually makes perfect sense. `pop` is a 1-byte instruction, while `add esp, x` is a 3-byte instruction. So, as long as you're doing 2 or fewer `pop`s, that's 1 byte less than an `add`. Once you do three `pop`s, that's the same size as an `add`, but the `add` would be faster, so it wins.

Now, what doesn't make sense to me is how you are getting the compiler to output the assembly code shown in the question. I tried several different ways to reverse-engineer this, turning it into equivalent C code, but I never managed to succeed. The issue is that MSVC never re-uses parameters left on the stack.

Looking at the code, we have:

> ```
> push    ebp
> mov     ebp, esp
> ```

which is the standard prologue code, a dead give-away that you must be compiling *without* omitting frame pointers ([`/Oy-`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2kxx5t2c.aspx)).

> ```
> push    ecx
> push    [ebp+arg_4]
> push    [ebp+arg_0]
> call    sub_00000000
> ```

If `ecx` is meaningful at this point in the function, it is probably a member function of a C++ class, which follows the `__thiscall` calling convention, passing the `this` pointer in `ecx`. And since it pushes `ecx` onto the stack, you must be calling a free function that takes a class-object pointer as the third parameter. Something like:

```
RetVal sub_00000000(int arg_0, int arg_4, CClass* pClass);
```

This works fine, and I can easily craft code that generates similar assembly output. Problem is, I can never get this instruction:

> ```
> add     esp, 8
> ```

because *three* parameters were pushed onto the stack. That's 12 bytes, not 8 bytes, so this code *should* be cleaning up 12 bytes from the stack. The only way it would make sense to only clean 8 bytes would be if you were calling a second function that took `pClass` as its sole parameter. But, as I said, MSVC never re-uses parameters that have already been pushed onto the stack, even if it knows they are `const`. It'll always start over fresh, re-pushing the parameters for the second function call, so you'll see something like:

```
push    ebp              ; \  prologue
mov     ebp, esp         ; /   code
push    esi              ; preserve esi
mov     esi, ecx         ; make copy of ecx
push    esi              ; \
push    [ebp+arg_4]      ; |  push parameters for 1st function call
push    [ebp+arg_0]      ; /
call    sub_00000000
push    esi              ; push parameters for 2nd function call
call    sub_00000001
add     esp, 16          ; clean stack
...
```

Anyway, it probably would have been easier if you'd posted the original C code you were looking at. That would have made it much easier for me to try compiling it on different versions of the compiler, with different compilation options, to see if I could reproduce something closer.

Here is one interesting observation. If we have code like the following:

```
struct Foo
{
   bool Caller(int one, int two);
};

struct RetStruct
{
   unsigned long lo;
   unsigned long hi;
};

RetStruct* Callee(int one, int two, Foo* pFoo);

bool Foo::Caller(int one, int two)
{
   return (Callee(one, two, this)->hi == 3);
}
```

and we compile it on VS 2010 (or older versions) with `/O1 /Oy-` (optimize for size, without omitting frame pointer), we get:

```
push   ebp
mov    ebp, esp
push   ecx
push   DWORD PTR _two$[ebp]
push   DWORD PTR _one$[ebp]
call   Callee
xor    ecx, ecx
add    esp, 12
cmp    DWORD PTR [eax+4], 3
...
```

Ignore that spurious `xor ecx, ecx` and this looks pretty close to your original code. Well, besides what I already pointed out about how only cleaning up *8* bytes from the stack doesn't make any sense.

Switching `/O1` for `/O2` (that is, optimizing for speed instead of size), we get:

```
push   ebp
mov    ebp, esp
mov    eax, DWORD PTR _two$[ebp]
push   ecx
mov    ecx, DWORD PTR _one$[ebp]
push   eax
push   ecx
call   Callee
xor    edx, edx
add    esp, 12
cmp    DWORD PTR [eax+4], 3
...
```

What changed? Well, again, ignoring the spurious `xor edx, edx`, what changed is that values are being loaded into registers first, and then pushed, rather than pushing memory operands. For some reason, MSVC thinks this is faster and therefore worth the increased code size.

But what happens on newer versions of MSVC? On both VS 2013 and VS 2015, we get *identical* output for `/O1` and `/O2`:

```
push   ebp
mov    ebp, esp
push   ecx
push   DWORD PTR _two$[ebp]
push   DWORD PTR _one$[ebp]
call   Callee
add    esp, 12
cmp    DWORD PTR [eax+4], 3
...
```

We also lose the spurious `xor`. :-) But the really significant thing here is that we can now optimize for speed (`/O2`) to get the desired stack-cleaning behavior (`add` instead of `pop`+`pop`), without changing how the parameters are pushed onto the stack.

So I would say that the original binary is *probably* compiled with a recent version of Visual Studio (VS 2013 or VS 2015), with the relevant option switches being `/O2 /Oy-`. Try that and see if it doesn't give you what you want.

Comment: The first `push ecx` might not be an argument. It could be allocating a single local variable on the stack, or maybe keeping the stack aligned.

Comment: @Cody Gray - Regardless of what you feel is pointless/better/faster/etc. your opinion does not matter to what I am doing and had nothing to do with the question. Doesn't matter what you think does or doesn't need to be done, the binary changes at random due to updates, so hard coding is not at all the better way to do this. Either way, I was just looking for info on controlling the compiler, if it can't be done then that was all I needed to know.

Comment: @epzap I don't know how to interpret that comment. You asked a question about how MSVC generates object code, and I posted a very thorough answer explaining how these optimizations are applied across different versions of the compiler, with several suggestions on how to get the results you want. I didn't ever use the word "pointless", and even when I was discussing things that are better/faster, I was referring to what the *compiler* is doing. I'm sorry that you were unsatisfied, but I stand by this answer. I think it is very helpful, and I think will be helpful to others.

Comment: I guess what you're trying to tell me (in an unusually hostile way, at least the way I read it) is that I could have saved a lot of time just by posting "No" in the answer box, with a bunch of spaces for filler. But I have higher standards than that for answers that I submit. If you don't like the rest of the advice, feel free to ignore it, I guess. Most people like Stack Overflow for the depth of knowledge provided here.